# Eclipse cant get key input on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and Eclipse Juno. This happens frequently: When I put focus in eclipse editor window, I can input few words in editor at the beginning, and then undo several times, Suddenly it happened that, I can't input any word in eclipse, that's strange problem.

Then, I change to other program and input anything, After that, back to eclipse it can accept my key again. It get me so frustrate.

Any one knows this problem? I am using desktop pc, memory is 1G.

Comment: I know this phenomenon but never cared to solve it myself. I don't think it's a memory issue as Chandrayya sugested. My machine has 16GB and I always grant Eclipse a lot of heap space. I always thought it was one of those Java under Unity issues. Besides that: 1GB of memory for Java development with Eclipse? This most likely will become an issue at some point.

Comment: I hope some one can talk about what's happened with eclipse? Why it don't accept key input? I tried upgrade kernel to latest 3.8.0-35, also can't solve the problem.

Comment: something like this bug, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=107013 It happened again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this problem; It is scim input method conflict with XIM(X Input Method) method.

Solution 1,

just **right click in eclipse workspace** -> **select Input Methods** -> **SCIM input methods**, that's OK. But, Every time you should do it while opening another file.

Solution 2, make scim as default system input methods.
Edit /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/scim as below:

```
XIM=SCIM
XIM_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/scim
XIM_ARGS="-d"
XIM_PROGRAM_SETS_ITSELF_AS_DAEMON=yes
#GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
#QT_IM_MODULE=xim
GTK_IM_MODULE=scim
QT_IM_MODULE=scim
```

also, add x95input file to /etc/X11/Xsession.d/95xinput

```
/usr/bin/scim -d
XMODIFIERS="@im=SCIM"
export XMODIFIERS
export GTK_IM_MODULE=scim
```

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 2):

This may help;

1. I guess you have lots of projects in your workspace and `Project->Build Automatically` option was enabled by default. Disable this and use `Project-Build All` or `Project-Build Project` commands before you start debugging your application OR If possible create two workspace and move some of your projects to other workspace. Note that you can open two instances of Eclipse on two different workspaces simultaneously.
2. Increase [heap space for Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F).
3. Its also possible that you installed many plug-ins in Eclipse. You can disable unnecessary plug-ins to load on eclipse start up as shown below

[image]

### Edit

Two more options.

```
1. Disable all options in **Highlighted** category of preferences. Restart eclipse.
```

[image]

```
2. Delete **.metadata** in your workspace and restart eclipse. Note!!!. All you preferences will be lost!!!
```

Comment: I uncheck the Build Automatically, and The heap space is '-Xms128m
-Xmx512m,--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m', I just installed adt plugin for android sdk. that's not the question, I think.

Comment: I faced such type of problem before and solved it myself by removing unwanted plug-ins from my workspace. Also check whether you enabled auto or scheduled synchronization with your source repository and check the heap status by enabling "Show heap status" option in preferences.

Comment: every time editing in eclipse, I notice the heap space is using about 110~128M. It's not like lack of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

I googled and found the answer

The answer is:

Right click in Editor area  InputMethods-Scim

*Editor area is where you write code